# pressing shift + v + space + w at the same time won't work

Tags: keyboard

I have a problem where when I click shift, space, w and x at the same time it does not work. I use this when playing a game and it it will not work. It allows me to click shift, space, w and c, but not 'x'. I cannot find a way to fix it and believe it might be a limitation of some sort but I want to be sure. I am also using a laptop running Windows 10 and it's a 64-bit system. If you have any ideas on what is going on or what I should do if I want to fix it, please do speak.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware issue.

Answer (score -1):

It is very likely that this is a limitation of the laptop keyboard. Lot's of keyboards still don't have what is called n-key rollover (aka nkro). n-key rollover means that you can press however many keys at the same time and they will register. You can test if this is the case by testing these four buttons at the same time on a website like [keyboardtester.com](http://www.keyboardtester.com/).